# Is there a way in TypeScript to say "Include" (opposite of Exclude)?

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, strong-typing

I have a String Union that looks like:
`type AlphabetLike = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'zeta' | 'beta' | 'gamma' | 'mu';`
I want to be able to construct the type
`type Alphabet = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'`. I could do this by using Exclude and removing zeta, beta, gamma, and mu but that's a lot of things to remove and if more values are added to AlphabetLike, it changes Alphabet. I want to know if my value from "AlphabetLike" is ever removed from that type.

Is there a way to do an Include instead of an Exclude?

Answer (score 11):

There is an [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) which acts like the opposite of [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion):

```
type AlphabetLike = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'zeta' | 'beta' | 'gamma' | 'mu';

type Alphabet = Extract<AlphabetLike, 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'zzz'>;
// type Alphabet = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Note that nothing forces the second argument (called `U` here) to either `Extract<T, U>` or `Exclude<T, U>` to contain only elements from the first argument (called `T` here).  Hence that `'zzz'` above doesn't have an effect on anything.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNmAFgQwEYWAGQJYGtoC8UA5MsVAD4mrlXEDGtJAXhmZdW08QObIC2-dnX4BXYgG4AsAChZoSLAQp0wKEQCiAD2AAnZPWAAeeEjQYc+ADQlh1bow7FmL4gD5pMgPReoC6KYqGOpQAETIoRyhqJFUofShsrJAA)

Comment: That's so weird. I swore I tried this and it didn't do what I wanted but I think maybe my understanding of the problem evolved as I played around and I forgot to come back to this.

Answer (score 0):

A double "exclude" can act as an include.

First, create a list of all of the items you want to exclude if you were using exclude.

```
type GreekAlphabet = Exclude<AlphabetLike, 'a' | 'b' | 'c'>
```

This results in a set that is:
`'zeta' | 'beta' | 'gamma' | 'mu'`
We can use that set with Exclude to give us back the values we want:

```
type Alphabet = Exclude<AlphabetLike, GreekAlphabet>
```

This results in:
`'a' | 'b' | 'c'`
which is effectively `Include<AlphabetLike, 'a'|'b'|'c'>` and will protect you if an option in use is removed from "AlphabetLike".